# Javascript on carousel breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I made an update to this page: http://www.thesanfordcenter.net/sanford-center and now my carousel broke on me. It should have 4 items that are able to slide right and left, but now it is showing all of the items. I am pretty new to javascript and jQuery, so I apologize in advance if I seem a bit slow. Thank you for any help as to why this is broken.

Comment: And now it seems to be working again. I feel that it might be some weird conflict with xpstickybar.js It seems to work after commenting "jQuery.noConflict" out in that file. I am not sure what the proper fix to this would be though.